# Same Arrangements of the word "MINIMUM"

Tags: combinatorics

In how many distinguishable ways can the seven letters in the word MINIMUM be arranged, if all the letters are used each time?

My attempt:
3!(2!) = 12 ways.

M has 3 choices and I has two choices. These ways are mutually exclusive(independent) so multiply.

How am I wrong?

Comment: So, you are only allowing rearrangements that still spell "MINIMUM"? Usually, this sort of problem allows non-words, like `IIMMMUN`

Comment: @ThomasAndrews yes.

Comment: If this is homework, I'll bet you will find out you are misinterpreting the question, and that you are expected to come up with all rearrangements. If you can post the act text of the question, it might help to clarify.

Comment: this is prep for a multiple choice test. no written work counts on the test

Comment: Well, the answer you selected is an answer to the wrong question, if you are sure about the meaning of the question. That answer is for arbitrary rearrangements of the letters. My point wasn't about whether you were trying to do homework here, but whether you were reading the question right. If you made up the question out of your head, you can mean whatever you want, but, if you are reading the question somewhere, you seem to be misreading a very common sort of question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since MINIMUM has seven letters, you have seven positions to fill.  You can fill three of them with M's in $\binom{7}{3}$ ways.  You now have four positions to fill.  You can fill two of them with I's in $\binom{4}{2}$ ways.  You now have two positions left to fill.  You can fill one of them with an N in $\binom{2}{1}$ ways.  You can fill the final position with a U in $\binom{1}{1}$ way.  Hence, the number of distinguishable arrangements of the letters of the word MINIMUM is

$$\binom{7}{3}\binom{4}{2}\binom{2}{1}\binom{1}{1} = \frac{7!}{4!3!} \cdot \frac{4!}{2!2!} \cdot \frac{2!}{1!1!} \cdot \frac{1!}{1!0!} = \frac{7!}{3!2!1!1!}$$

Answer (score 1):

This can be found using the [multinomial theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Multinomial_theorem).  Here, we have

$$\frac {7!}{3!2!}\,\text{ possible distinct combinations}$$ where $7$ is the the length of the word "minimum", $3$ is the number of "m's" we have to work with, and $2$ is the number of "i"'s we have on hand to work with.

Answer (score 0):

Pretending that you have a 7 letter word with all different letters, there would be 7!. However since there are repeating letters, it's 7!/(3!2!1!1!) because there's 3 M's, 2 I's, 1 N, and 1 U.

For more reading, see this [link](https://people.richland.edu/james/lecture/m116/sequences/counting.html). Read under Distinguishable Permutations.